# Jupyter Notebook Can't Import my TestPyPI package

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, package, cython, pypi

I'm new to package publishing and thought I would start with a test one. The only complication it uses a very basic Cython module (the package I actually want to upload is Cython based). The Git is: https://github.com/Jacks0nJ/Package_test.git and the package can be found at https://test.pypi.org/project/example-package-Joe-Jackson/.

I can install it to my Linux machine and run the package just fine in a virtual environment, i.e. can import and run both the Python module and Cython module, with the expected output. The problem is that when I install it on a Jupyter Notebook using

```
! python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps example-package-Joe-Jackson
```

and then try to import a module inside it

```
import example_package.example
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example_package'
```

This error even persits when I install the earlier version without Cython.
Note, while my package is called example-package-Joe-Jackson, the module is example_package (this is simply due to the convention of the guide I used: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Is there a simple fix to this importing problem? Do I need to import it in a different way? Or is it simply TestPyPI does not work on a Notebook? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try from inside your notebook, replacing `! python3 -m pip install` with `%pip install`?

Comment: Worked! Cheers! Very glad it's a simple import mistake rather than a problem with my package! I normally use Spyder rather than Jupyter to run my code, so now I just feel very silly

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic commands `%pip install` and `%conda install`. These are now the best practice for when you are doing installs within a cell within Jupyter notebook. Avoid using an exclamation point with `pip` or `conda` as you can sometimes get it doing things in an environment that is not the same as you are using your notebook kernel, which seems to have happened when you used the `!`. There's a lot of outdated info out there with `!`.

Comment: @Wayne I might be missing something but when I try to install a package from testpypi I get the following error `AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'` The command I run is `%pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ doip-client`

Comment: @bhspencer With `%pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ doip-client` I get that it cannot find matching distribution in my case. And the `%pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps example-package-Joe-Jackson` works so the issue with `doip-clinet` is particular to the package and not testpypi.

Comment: @Wayne thanks for trying. The thing is I can run `python3 -m pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ doip-client` from the macOS terminal and it installs just fine. This is my test package so I can change it as needed but its not at all clear to me what would need to change to get it to install in Jupyter. Do you have an insight into the error message `AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'`?

Comment: @Wayne more data. If I create a new jupyter notebook on jupyter.org. I select the default kernal. I enter the command that you are able to run `%pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps example-package-Joe-Jackson` I get the same error.

What are you doing differently?

Comment: Does your kernel indicate `pyolite`? You'd see in the upper right side, I think. You cannot use `Try Jupyter` anymore for more than just trying the interface. The main resources there now use JupyterLite which uses micropip, **NOT PIP**. Plus, they should be clearly marked AS EXPERIMENTAL. To get a normal, full Python-backed session: Go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and press `launch binder`. When that session comes up, open a new notebook and try  the commands.